# Biggest n that can be solved in one second

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification, algorithms

I have been given the following problem:

What is the largest n for which one can solve in one second a problem that requires $(\log_2(n))^2$
elementary operations, where each elementary operation is carried out in $10^{−12}$ second?

I have the following solution:

$(\log_2(n))^2 = 10^{12}$

$\log_2(n) = 10^{6}$

$n = 2^{10^6}$

Is my reasoning (and ultimately, the solution) correct?

Comment: Prefix a 'log' with a backslash to make it upright: `log` looks like a multiplication of $l$ and $o$ and $g$: $log = l\cdot o\cdot g$, while `\log` stands for a function name: $\log$.

Comment: @CiaPan - thanks for the tip!

Comment: Just for fun : The number $\approx 9.9\times 10^{301029}$ ! Thats big!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes your computations and your answer looks correct.

Comment: Should be a comment :)

Comment: @NeilRoy Well I disagree with you. If we just answer that as a comment, then this question will stay in the unanswered list (which is already very long...).

Comment: @NeilRoy http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/20097/how-to-answer-proof-verification-questions

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/20098/134694 (The answer)!

Comment: @NeilRoy yes but quid precised "most of the time" and I don't see any way to improve the answer of OP (maybe because some context is missing). The only thing I see that I could do is to copy past your $2^{10^6}\approx 9.9 \times 10^{301029}$

Comment: Agree with Surb that this should be posted as an answer. (You can post it as community wiki though)

Comment: @JohnMa done, although I'm not sure if the community really helped me to check the answer :)